# Visual Studio error cannot call method on int

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

Just Trying to insert some simple data into a table but every time I try I get the error "cannot call method on int". Here is my code, thanks for any help data types in table are int for cinema Id and nvarchar(50) for ReviewText

```
protected void BtnSubmitReview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {           
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("RegistrationConnectionString");

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ReviewText (ReviewText.CinemaID, ReviewText.ReviewText) VALUES (1, 'NorthWestern')";
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

            sqlConnection1.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection1.Close();

            Response.Write("Your Review was saved");                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error" + ex.ToString());
        }
```

Error Shown:

> Cannot call methods on int.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot call methods on int.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot call methods on int.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5352418    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds) +1406
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +177
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +53
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +134
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +41
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +10    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +140
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +316

Comment: Can you post the actual error/stacktrace?

Comment: Are you putting an actual connection string in the `SqlConnection` constructor or putting in "RegistrationConnectionString" ?

Comment: ResgistrationConnectionString is a connection i was using on another page for inserting other data into the database , just using it again instead of creating new connection

Comment: The Problem was that I was using the name of the table for the name of one of the columns , The query must get mixed up if you do so, thanks

Comment: @user3542214 I answered your question, mentioning the problem, but I get -1 :(((

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to qualify the column names in your `INSERT` statement with the table name. Use this as your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO ReviewText (CinemaID, ReviewText) VALUES (1, 'NorthWestern')
```

Also, If you are looking for a connection string in your application/web.config you can't just put the key in the `SqlConnection` constructor to get the actual connection string. You have to use the `ConfigurationManager` class to get value, which would look something like this:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code has a problem and I don't know if this problem is the root of your exception or not, please first edit it to this and then tell us the result:

```
    //you dont need to repeat table name in insert command's columns
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ReviewText (CinemaID, ReviewText) VALUES (1, 'NorthWestern')";
```

also it is highly recommended to use SqlConnection via this way:

```
using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("RegistrationConnectionString"))
{
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ReviewText (CinemaID, ReviewText) VALUES (1, 'NorthWestern')";
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();

}
```

Comment: Probably because it doesn't really answer the question. Even if your fix is correct, it isn't obvious what the difference is between the OPs code and yours, nor is there any explanation why his code is incorrect. If it is a simple change, just ask him to make it in the comments.

Comment: The difference with your code and the OP's code is not visible at all! I used a diff tool to find the difference! Instead of pasting the whole code and changing a few words, you could just write the changed line. Also by doing a simple test, you could find out "if this problem is the root of the exception or not".